# ANTLR Parser Rules With String Literals

Tags: parsing, antlr, lexer

Say if my parser rules look like this:

```
rule1 : 'functionA' '(' expression-inside-parenthesis ')'; 
expression-inside-parenthesis: ....;
```

But I never defined any lexer rule for 'functionA', '(' and ')'.  Would these be considered tokens by the parser? For '(' and ')', there is only 1 character anyway and I suppose there would be no difference.  But for 'functionA', if I never defined it as a token in my lexer rules, how could the parser see it as a token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***JavaMan wrote:***
>
> how could the parser see it as a token?

ANTLR creates a token for you behind the scenes.

The rule:

```
rule1 : 'functionA' '(' expression-inside-parenthesis ')';
// parser rules ...
// lexer rules  ...
```

is equivalent to:

```
rule1 : FA '(' expression-inside-parenthesis ')';
// parser rules ...
FA : 'functionA';
// lexer rules  ...
```

In case of tokens that only consist of 1 character and do not occur within other tokens, like `'('` and `')'`, it is okay to define them "on the fly" inside your parser rule, put as soon as your lexer grammar also contains identifier-like tokens, it's best to explicitly define a token like `'functionA'` yourself inside the lexer grammar. By defining them yourself explicitly, it is clearer in what order the lexer tries to tokenize your input.

#### EDIT

And in case you've used a literal-token and defined a lexer rule that matches the same, like this:

```
parse : 'functionA' ID;
FA    : 'functionA';
ID    : 'a'..'z'+;
```

then ANTLR interprets the `parse` rule as this:

```
parse : FA ID;
```

Comment: What'd happen if I define an FA lexer rule just like your example but also use the 'functionA' literal inside my parser rule?  Now there're 2 definitions for 'functionA', one is my FA lexer rule, another is the implicit definition created by the lexer.